# JsTree rename, delete and create functions

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jstree

I've been looking over JStree documents, but I can't seem to get these buttons to function permanently.

Please help, thank you.

JSP:

```
<div col-xs-12 id="button-row4">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="delete_node" onclick="demo_create();">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
        Create
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="demo_rename();">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
        Rename
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="demo_delete();">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
<div id="jstree_demo_div"> *tree data list* </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#jstree_demo_div").jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': coredata
    },
    'search': {
        "case_insensitive": true,
        "show_only_matches" : true
    },
    'plugins': ["search"]
});

$('#jstree_demo_div').on("select_node.jstree",
    function(evt, data){
        console.log('id '+ JSON.stringify(data.node.id));
        console.log('text '+ JSON.stringify(data.node.text));
        console.log('li_attr '+ JSON.stringify(data.node.li_attr));
    }
);
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, this didnt work